# Rails 4 includes multiple has_many and belongs_to index.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, twitter-bootstrap-3, nested-includes

How would I handle a belong_to with the following include. Instead of displaying the product_colour_id id like to show the associated colour (**Update:Solved this part below**). The product_colour_id is in the Product table and matches the corresponding Product_colour id.

***Its the case of two or more has_many associations that i cant work out. Can it be done?***

**app/controller/home_controller.rb**

```
  class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    products = Product.last(5)
    product_ids = products.map(&:id)   
    @product_colour_ids = products.map(&:product_colour_id)
    @allproduct_colours = ProductColour.all 
    @product_colour_map = ProductColour.find(@product_colour_ids)   
    @product_images = Product.includes(:product_images)
                    .where(product_images: {product_id: product_ids, :default_image => true})
  end
end
```

**/app/views/home/index.html.erb**

```
<% @product_images.each do |pd| %>
          <%= content_tag :div, :class => "col-md-3 col-sm-6 hero-feature" do %>
          <% pd.product_images.each do |i| %>
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <%= image_tag (i.product_image(:medium)) %>
          <% end %> </div>
          <div class="caption">
            <h3><%= pd.product_name %></h3>
            <p><%= pd.product_description %></p>
            <p> <%= pd.product_colour_id %></p>
          </div>
          <% end %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
```

I'm having difficulty finding examples of multiple has_many includes. I assume there is a very straight forward pattern to it but cant work it out from [apidock](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes) or [api.rubyonrails.org](http://api.rubyonrails.org/). The problem i'm having is adding the Supply_company which is a has_many :through relationship to the one I already have with the product_image include.

Thankyou in advance for your advise

**Update** I have worked out how to display the belongs_to... feeling a little dumb on that as it was very easy just needed some time to think

```
 <% pd.product_images.each do |pd| %>
   <p> <%= pd.product_colour.product_colour %></p>
 <% end %>
```

**/app/models/product.rb**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product_type
  belongs_to :product_category
  belongs_to :product_colour
  belongs_to :product_size

  has_many :product_supply_companies, :foreign_key => 'product_id'
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_supply_companies, :allow_destroy => true
  has_many :supply_companies, :through => :product_supply_companies
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :supply_companies

  has_many :product_images, dependent: :destroy, :foreign_key => 'product_id'
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_images, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

**app/models/product_supply_company.rb**

```
class ProductSupplyCompany < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :supply_company

 # accepts_nested_attributes_for :supply_company
 # accepts_nested_attributes_for :product

end
```

**app/models/supply_company.rb**

```
class SupplyCompany < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :products, :through => :product_supply_companies
  has_many :product_supply_companies, :foreign_key => 'supply_company_id'

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :products
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_supply_companies, :allow_destroy => true

end
```

**app/models/product_colour.rb**

```
class ProductColour < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
end
```

**Database Schema**

```
 create_table "product_categories", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "product_category"
    t.string   "product_category_description"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "product_colours", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "product_colour"
    t.string   "product_colour_description"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "product_images", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "product_id",                 null: false
    t.datetime "created_at",                 null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                 null: false
    t.string   "product_image_file_name"
    t.string   "product_image_content_type"
    t.integer  "product_image_file_size"
    t.datetime "product_image_updated_at"
    t.boolean  "default_image"
  end

  create_table "product_sizes", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "product_size"
    t.string   "product_size_description"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "product_supply_companies", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "product_id"
    t.integer  "supply_company_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "product_types", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "product_type"
    t.string   "product_type_description"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "products", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "product_name"
    t.text     "product_description"
    t.integer  "product_type_id"
    t.integer  "product_category_id"
    t.string   "product_colour_id"
    t.integer  "product_size_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

Comment: add associations in your post

Comment: Models added. Not sure how to add the supply_company  has_many, :through relationship to the one that's already done for the product_images.

Comment: do you have product_type_id, product_category_id, product_colour_id, product_size_id in your products table?

Comment: Correct except for the many to many relationship for the supply_company. I can do a single has_many and belong_to, but uncertain how to achieve a has_many :through or multiple has_many relationships. So how to extend this to include the supply_companies  @product_images = Product.includes(:product_images)
                    .where(product_images: {product_id: product_ids, :default_image => true})

Comment: Added an answer. Your solution had me thinking and it turns out I was trying to make the associations too complected and could actually be achieved without adding in more includes. Cheers for your answer it actually directed me to a solution though different. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@products = Product.includes(:product_images, :colour, :supply_companies)
                   .where(product_images: {product_id: product_ids, :default_image => true})
                   .select('products.*, product_colours.product_colour')
```

this the query with all associations.

index.html.erb

```
<% @products.each do |pd| %>
    <%= content_tag :div, :class => "col-md-3 col-sm-6 hero-feature" do %>
    <% pd.product_images.each do |i| %>
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <%= image_tag (i.product_image(:medium)) %>
        </div>
    <% end %> 
    <div class="caption">
      <h3><%= pd.product_name %></h3>
      <p><%= pd.product_description %></p>
      <p><%= pd.product_colour %></p>
    </div>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Product.rb

```
belongs_to :colour, class: 'ProductColor', foreign_key: 'product_colour_id'
```

Comment: That's got me their. Through some trial and error it seems that I don't need to use includes at all to access the has_many :through relationship or belongs_to it was useful for the images as I needed to filter them based on Product Ids and default_image Boolean. I had been thinking about the problem all wrong. It could all mostly be done by the code above directly in the index.html.erb. I'll post working code . Thank you for the push user123 :-)

Answer (score 0):

For those that follow. User123 gave me some ideas that finally provided a solution. I had been over thinking the problem mostly.

**app/controller/home_controller.rb**

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    products = Product.last(5)   ## find last five products 
    product_ids = products.map(&:id) ## map their ids so I can retrieve
    images with matching id's

    ## create array of products with corresponding default_images.
    ## Not necessary to include has_many, has_many :through or 
    ## belongs_to as they can be added directly on index.html.erb page

    @products = Product.includes(:product_images)
                    .where(product_images: {product_id: product_ids, :default_image => true}).last(5)

  end
end
```

**/app/views/home/index.html.erb**

```
  <% @products.each do |pd| #1st level directly access product_attributes %>
      <%= content_tag :div, :class => "col-md-3 col-sm-6 hero-feature" do %>

           <% pd.product_images.each do |i| # 2nd access has_many with
             foreign key in different table %>
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <%= image_tag (i.product_image(:medium)) %>
              </div>
          <% end %>

            <div class="caption">
            <h3><%= pd.product_name %></h3>
            <p><%= pd.product_description %></p>
            <p><%= pd.product_colour.product_colour #first level access 
                   belong_to relationship attributes %></p>

            <p><% pd.supply_companies.each do |sc| # 2nd level again to
                     access has_many :through relationship only done again for 
                     layout purposes. %></p>
                  <%= sc.company_name %>
            <% end %>
          </div>
      <% end %>
  <% end %>
```